# Parsing a json to an array

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a json response from backend like:

JSON:

```
[
  ["Bondi Beach",-33.890542,151.274856,4],
  ["Coogee Beach",-33.923036,151.259052,5],
  ["Cronulla Beach",-34.028249,151.157507,3],
  ["Manly Beach",-33.80010128657071,151.28747820854187,2],
  ["Maroubra Beach",-33.950198,151.259302,1]
]
```

How can I parse it to an array like:

```
[
  ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
  ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
  ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
  ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
  ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
]
```

Comment: Er, isn't it already in that format? I don't see the difference

Comment: nope its due to copy paste its json string first one @CertainPerformance

Comment: Both are in the same format. Parsing it with the standard JSON.parse method will work. If it doesn't, your problem is somewhere else. (maybe you don't need to JSON.parse it at all, and instead can just use it.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON.parse(array);

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: does not work tried.

Comment: @spacex then we need more information